# There Should Be a Link to Meta

Tags: discussion, chat

Why there's no link on the main site Russian Stackexchange connecting it to its meta? I found it by chance and I believe new participants don't know about its existence. There's no chat where learners could talk to native speakers and discuss minor problems or simply communicate improving both Russian and English. It could attract more people.

Finally, I think nobody will notice and answer these questions...because there's no link.

Comment: So I am, found this site just by typing http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com, thought it should exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... there is a link to meta, but you sort of have to know where to look: click the Stack Exchange logo/wordmark on the left end of the top bar and you'll see meta as the second link. (This works for any site in the network and its matching meta site, actually.)

There are no immediate plans to make the meta link more obvious, but suggestions are always welcome if you have an idea where it might go. I should note that some people are against the meta link being *too* prominent, because meta is not supposed to be a "main attraction" on its own and distract people from on-topic Q&A.

Comment: Thank you very much, as you see I am not the only one who didn't know that, and nobody could answer as well.

Comment: As for a proper place,  it would be easily found near "chat" at the bottom of the page.